# Creating a new branch and want to get changes from the master

Tags: git, github

So, I have just merged a feature branch to master and currently master has the latest code.

Now, I want to create a new feature branch and want to start working on it with the code that is currently in master. What should I do? Where do I checkout and pull?

Does `git pull` do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you checkout master, you're switching to that codebase.  When you pull from origin, you're updating your *local copy* to whatever is on the codebase.  When you checkout a new branch, you start from the previous branches codebase.

```
git checkout master
git pull origin master
git checkout -b <new branch>
```

That should work.

To see what will be merged before actually merging you can use this instead of `pull`

```
git fetch origin master
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming, you want online master branch changes irrespective of what you have on local master. Execute the following commands in order:

`1 - git checkout master
2 - git fetch origin master
3 - git reset --hard origin/master
4 - git checkout -b <your_branch_name>`

This will take care in case you get any local merge conflict while using "git pull origin master"

Comment: Be careful with this as it will clear and untracked files.